# How to export and import views from GravityView from one site to another?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

The only [solution online](https://docs.gravitykit.com/article/119-importing-and-exporting-configured-views) is to use WP default importer/exporter but it grabs ALL the posts from the source site. I just need to move views from GravityView.

How can I do it?